# Must a binary time series with a constant mean be stationary?

Tags: time-series, binary-data, stationarity

Suppose I have a binary time series $Y$ with support $\{0,1\}$ and a constant mean (i.e. $E[Y_t]=\mu,\forall t$). I know that this means the variance of the series is constant in time as well since, for a binary variable $X$, $Var(X)=E[X](1-E[X])$. However, do these conditions ensure that the autocorrelation of the series is independent of time and, thus, that the process is stationary? Does there exist a counterexample to such a claim?

Comment: Marginal distributions do not determine joint distributions.  That observation makes it easy to construct counterexamples.  I describe one in an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/408342/919: it exhibits a stationary process with unit correlation coefficients, rather than zero correlation coefficients.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that there is not necessarily a general relationship between one and the other, but my question here is whether one remaining constant over time ensures the other one is as well. A binary time series of constant mean can certainly have a non-zero correlation function, but can this function change over time without changing the mean over time?

Comment: Suppose you have two such time series, both stationary, but with different correlations.  (You know of at least two at this point.)  Terminate one and start the other up: there's an example of a changing correlation function.

Comment: You got me, that makes a lot of sense.